# Please htlp me to add datepicker(Jquery Ui)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Please htlp me! I want to add datepicker(Jquery Ui) and add one position in the script for counting... my knowledge is very small in jquery. (my english just little, too... sorry)
I will be grateful for your help
please see this code -
http://jsfiddle.net/konstantin_nd/kJpjw/48/

Comment: Question uncleared. If you want to add jQuery Datepicker, follow fitig answer and read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but I'm guessing you want to replace the selects for startdate with the datepicker widget from jQuery UI?
If so you first need to include the UI library, replace your dropdowns with an input with `id="datepicker"` and then initialize the datepicker on the DOM ready event. If you still want to use the dropdowns for the to-date you could get the from-date from the datepicker textbox.
Read through the documentation at http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ and then clarify your question.

**EDIT:** I've made som changes to your code to illustrate how you can use the datepicker widget. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/zXQdy/1/

Comment: Thanks for your help! see this link! please   http://jsfiddle.net/konstantin_nd/kJpjw/48/

Comment: I've edited the fiddle to get it working. I moved the datepicker initialization from the change event of the dropdowns to the DOM ready event and added logic to read the selected date from the arrival and departure textboxes. You probably also should add logic to handle invalid/non-existant dates in the change event. I hope this gives you an idea of how to use the datepicker widget.

Comment: Flitig, thank you! I am trying to solve this problem. until it fails. Documentation for Jqury learn ... version my code today is:
<br/>
$("#arrivalDate, #departureDate").datepicker({<br/>
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});

$('.recalc').change(function() {

var arrival = $('#arrivalDate').datepicker('getDate');
var sdmy = arrival.split('-');    
var startDate = new Date(
       parseInt(sdmy[2], 10),
       parseInt(sdmy[1], 10) - 1,
       parseInt(sdmy[0], 10) + 1);
<br/>
They are your letters, I realized that you have corrected the error. Give me a link please

Comment: I'm not sure what you want exactly but have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zXQdy/1/

Comment: Thank you. almost exactly what I need. the sum counts the number of days. I need to get the number of nights. but this issue will decide himself. Thank you!

Comment: @userKonstantin if my solution solves your problem, you should mark the answer as such